Data Hazard in MIPS(RAW forwarding)
If I read and write a same register in one cycle, how to realize the Read After Write on hardware? Bypass will work but I'm wondering how to make it by trigger edge? Will it be ok if I write at the rising edge and read at the falling edge?
Or just write at the rising edge and then make a delay? How to make the delay then?
Please forgive my poor English and thank you for your generous help. Below is an example of my problem:
add $r1, $r2, $r3
Inst 1
Inst 2
add $r2, $r1, $r3

In this case, the two add instructions both use Register File in the same cycle. The first one is writing back to r1 and the second one is reading from r1. How to realize it on hardware? If probable and convenient, could you please provide me with a simple verilog code to help me figure it out? Thanks again.
I tried searching on the Internet however find nothing.
I hope to figure out how it's realized on hardware and how it turns into a verilog code.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a CPU design question, not a computer programming question.

On a cycle that the write port is active at the same time as one of the read ports on that same register number, then the written value should simply flow through to the read port naturally.  You may find the stale register value appears on the read lines initially but should settle to the newly written value quickly, since that new value being written is available at the very top of that overlapping cycle, and it is only a few muxes further away.
